# User authentication Session is set from the start

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm working on page authentication. It can login already, but I want it to make user authentication on other pages aswell if someone tries to access pages through URL. If the person is not a logged in user, redirect that person to the login page. I tried it by working with sessions but it doesn't work. I'm following MVC structure 
Somehow the sessions never gets unset. I don't know why..

Here is how I did it

My loginController

```
    <?php
//LoginController
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == "login")
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        try
        {
            include '../model/Login.php';
            $login = new Login($db, $username, $password);

            if($login == TRUE)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location:../index.php");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception $exc)
        {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

My index controller( for main page)

```
<?php
include 'model/Database.php';
session_start();
//Checks if the user is logged in.
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
//echo"<h2>You have no access to this page!";
    include 'view/login.php';
    die();
}
include 'c:/wamp/www/mvc/model/Display.php';

$displayPatients = new Display($db);
$dataDisplay = $displayPatients->getData();
include 'view/Main.php';
?>
```

my logout.php: When a user clicks this button:

```
<?php

//Logout
//destroys the session when the user clicks logout
session_destroy();
header('Location:view/login.php'); //redirect to the login
```

The user does get logged out redirected to the login page but the session is still set. The session is set from the beginning and I have no idea why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taken out of the manual for the session_destroy()

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

So it seems to me you need to destroy your session id or set it to something else when starting the new session otherwise your next sesson_start() resumes the old session again.

For this reason you could also just regenerate the session id on login before redirecting. Ah and it's always a good idea to use "exit;" after a "Location:" redirect via "header()".

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: So you mean it's enough if I put `session_regenerate_id(true);` after `session_start();`? I tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: At a second look your problem might be lying in a completely different place. Did you even start the session before calling session_destroy() because I do not see this in your logout.php script? You won't be able to destroy the correct session otherwise (or any for that matter).